# Creating custom modules in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I need to create an application with joomla. What is the best way to go about this? create plugable modules or component? And can any of this interact with an external database?

Answer (score 0):

An application with Joomla? Do you mean your own component with modules or do you wanna use the Joomla framework itself for developing an application? Depends on what yo wanna do i guess.
No matter what you do, you can always use the Joomla Framework to easily access the DB.

```
$db         = &JFactory::getDbo(); 
$db->setQuery('SELECT * FROM mytable');  
$data = $db->loadObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple Webapp you may use [Joomla Platform](http://docs.joomla.org/Platform/11.1).

For more complex webapps, in my opinion it's better to use stripped Joomla bundle with own main component and modules/ plugins as helpers.

If you want to use external database, it's possible to use JDatabase class (see Joomla docs: [How to connect to an external database](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_connect_to_an_external_database)) in the same way you'd interact with native database. However if you'd like to use it in more places than one component model, I advise creating a component helper which will load external database configuration from your component parameters.